# Javascript onclick function error Cannot read property 'inv' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript function as below:

```
function myClickEvent(params) {
    var inv = $("#" + params["inv"]);
    inv.on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: params["route"],
            contentType: "text/json",
            success: function (result) {
                history.pushState(null, null, params["route"]);
                $("#content-wrapper").html(result);
                inv.parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
                inv.parent().addClass("active");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

I am calling this into my html file like this:

```
<button onclick='myClickEvent()'>Click me</button>
```

It is showing error

> Cannot read property 'inv' of undefined

How to test this function?

Comment: you need to pass some params. myClickEvent(), you aren't passing anything and expecting something on function call

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? What do you expect your code to do?

Comment: @McRist Like what? I don't have anything to pass

Comment: can you provide some html code and also the skeleton of the object you pass as argument (params)

Comment: @SLaks to display a message through Ajax

Comment: @Jsmith My html code is this button. Function js file is already included

Comment: _Read your own code_.  If your function takes a parameter, you need to pass it.  It's up to you to figure out what parameter you want to pass.

Answer (score 2):

`params` is supposed to be a Javascript object with the `inv` property, which you have not provided as an argument to the function.

```js
function myClickEvent(params) {
    var inv = $("#" + params["inv"]);
    inv.on("click", function () {
       console.log(inv+": clicked");
        //$.ajax({
           // url: params["route"],
            //contentType: "text/json",
            //success: function (result) {
               // history.pushState(null, null, params["route"]);
       //         $("#content-wrapper").html(result);
               // inv.parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
     //           inv.parent().addClass("active");
          //  }
      //  });
      //  return false;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='myClickEvent({inv: "test"})'>Click me</button>
<p/>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Click me button is not doing anything. Can you explain?

Comment: @CH_user303 Click it and then click on the test button.

Comment: but i dont want to display two buttons :(

Comment: @CH_user303 Do you not know what your own code does? If you don't want this behavior, then remove the usage of `params`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not passing anything to the function, you can test it this way

`<button onclick='myClickEvent("value")'>Click me</button>`

and then add `console.log(params)` in the first line of your function

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a javascript tutorial, you are telling the button to execute on click the function myClickEvent() without parameters, and in the definition you are expecting a params param, this is not filled by itself, i would tell you to add the param but what you really need to do is not to use the onClick attribute in html and use instead addEventListener from script in the button element.